# Delete all objects from hashmap that match specific condition

Tags: java, object, hashmap, getter

Following situation. I have:

```
public class Management {

    private HashMap<Integer, Book> allBooks = new HashMap<>();

    public void deleteAllBooksFromOwner(Owner owner) {
    }

    public class Owner {
        private String name;
        // getters
    }

    public class Book {
        private Owner owner;
        // getters
    }
}
```

I want to write a method in Management class to delete books:

```
public void deleteAllBooksFromOwner(Owner owner){
}
```

I don't know how to access the book owner, for my comparison.
Getters are available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `removeIf`

```
public void deleteAllBooksFromOwner(Owner owner) {
    allBooks.entrySet().removeIf(entry -> entry.getValue().getOwner().equals(owner));
}
```